# PHP - mysql query not working when using NOT LIKE

Tags: php, mysql

I have a query string being built and it works fine when I use LIKE but it will not work with NOT LIKE

```
 $sWhere = "";
    if ( $_GET['sSearch'] != "" )
    {

            $aWords = preg_split('/\s+/', $_GET['sSearch']);
            $sWhere = "WHERE (";

            for ( $j=0 ; $j<count($aWords) ; $j++ )
            {
                    if ( $aWords[$j] != "" )
                    {
                            if(substr($aWords[$j], 0, 1) == "!"){
                                    $notString = substr($aWords[$j], 1);
                                    $sWhere .= "(";
                                    for ( $i=0 ; $i<count($aColumns) ; $i++ )
                                    {
                                            $sWhere .= $aColumns[$i]." NOT LIKE '%".mysql_real_escape_string( $notString )."%' OR ";
                                    }
                            }
                            else{
                                    $sWhere .= "(";
                                    for ( $i=0 ; $i<count($aColumns) ; $i++ )
                                    {
                                            $sWhere .= $aColumns[$i]." LIKE '%".mysql_real_escape_string( $aWords[$j] )."%' OR ";
                                    }
                            }
                            $sWhere = substr_replace( $sWhere, "", -3 );
                            $sWhere .= ") AND ";
                    }
            }
            $sWhere = substr_replace( $sWhere, "", -4 );
```

the part of the code that does work is:

```
 if(substr($aWords[$j], 0, 1) == "!"){
                                    $notString = substr($aWords[$j], 1);
                                    $sWhere .= "(";
                                    for ( $i=0 ; $i<count($aColumns) ; $i++ )
                                    {
                                            $sWhere .= $aColumns[$i]." NOT LIKE '%".mysql_real_escape_string( $notString )."%' OR ";
                                    }
                            }
```

if I remove the "NOT" the query works fine but it does nothing when I add the NOT.

thanks

Comment: Explain `does nothing`. Obviously when you use `NOT LIKE` instead of `LIKE` you just get the opposite result set

Comment: Does this post help?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1638566/sql-not-like-statement-not-working

Comment: I see a lot of code, but not a single query. Quite odd for a MySQL question...

Comment: it is for the jquery dataTables plugin filtering... when I use like it returns the correct results but when I use NOT LIKE it just show all results and does no filtering...

Comment: the query is built up throughout much more code there is no issue with the query running just when I add the NOT in there therefore the only code necessary to view is that snippet

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because you are using `OR` in your NOT LIKE condition.

Finding all the rows where column1 NOT LIKE "a" OR column2 NOT LIKE "a" will match everything.

Comment: are you saying I shoudl be using AND?

Comment: Yes; to reverse its meaning, you need to do `NOT LIKE x AND NOT LIKE y`.

Comment: Learning a little about [De Morgan's law](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan's_laws) may help